# Any game kills my sound

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, audio

Every time I quit a game such as Braid, Fallout3, AVP all sound on the PC dies (Control Panel > No Audio Devices) I installed a new sound card (SB Audigy) and updated to the latest drivers, and it still happens.

It happens with Steam games and without.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest drivers, they *should* work. You can try uninstalling and reinstalling them.

If this doesn't work (and I imagine you're on Windows), find the "Sound" window - either right click the sound icon and then select "Sounds", find it in Control Panel or try to find it with search.

Right click on your device (in my case Focusrite USB sound card) and click Properties. Go to Advanced tab and see what "default format" options you have.
It should be 2 channels (for stereo, 1 channel is mono). Choosing 16 bit over 24 bit is more likely to work on all devices. The sample rate should be either 44100Hz or 48000Hz.
In any case, play around with settings and see if anything helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am shooting in the dark here as I encountered a similar issue with a creative soundcard on vista.

For me the drivers were buggy which caused a memory leak in the sound processing app. So what you need to do is when the sound is out press Ctr+alt+del( or Ctrl+alt+esc ) to bring the task manager and see if any application is using an unreal amount of memory (also see if the exe is related to sound/creative by googling it). In my case the issue was fixed by disabling the eax effects(or something like that).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It's Ctrl+Shift+Esc, not Ctrl+Alt+Esc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your audio driver and remove any additional plugins(dolby/SRS etc.) that where installed in your PC. This may sometimes help you

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Since I'm not having enough reputation, the only way to communicate is to post as an answer, once i get enough clarity about the problem, i can edit the answer. Really sorry about that.

Comment: You won't get any clarity from a five year old question ... ;) Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

If you used "IObit Driver booster", uninstall the newly installed driver and look for the required driver on the manufacturer's website. I've been through multiple computers due to driver booster updating a PCI bus driver causing all the drivers to disappear and make the computer unusable.

So uninstall the new driver, the driver booster, then look on this site for the required driver (http://support.creative.com/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?catID=1&prodID=4847&prodName=Sound%20Blaster%20Audigy&CatName=Sound+Blaster)

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting these audio services using the cmd console or the task manager.

```
net stop audiosrv
net stop AudioEndpointBuilder
net start audiosrv
net start AudioEndpointBuilder
```